# How to override action when field curyOrigDiscAmt value changes Acumatica ERP

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am customizing APInvoiceEntry graph, when it is modified in the ***Bills and Adjustments*** Screen (ID=AP301000).

The field **curyOrigDiscAmt** is set when items are added in the POItem portion of the graph. There is logic that calculates the discount based on payment type (eg Cash Prepayment) and what is set on the vendor class.
[image]

This is the default behavior. However, after that runs, I have logic I want to run that adjusts this figure.

I thought I could simply put my logic in a "field changing" method. But none of the actions I can find are activated when the change to **curyOrigDiscAmt** happens.

So far, I have tried:

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldVerifying<APInvoice, APInvoice.curyOrigDiscAmt> e)
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<APInvoice, APInvoice.curyOrigDiscAmt> e)
protected void APInvoice_CuryOrigDiscAmt_FieldUpdating(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)
protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelecting<APInvoice> e)
```

None of them fire when the field is changed. I need to reflected in the UI for the user to see, so it doesn't do any good to change it when the record is saved. I need it to happen right after the base code runs that does the calculation.

Where is that? How do I find it?

[EDIT -- Follow-up to Hugues Beauséjour's answer below]

Is there a way to just raise the events without having to change the CalcDisc()  method at all? All I need are the events to be called.

In other words something sort of like:

```
protected override void CalcDisc(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
 {
     base.CalcDisc(sender, e);
     base.RaiseEvents(EVENTLIST_TO_RAISE);
 }
```

I would rather not change the code at all if I could help it to keep it more bulletproof to future changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is computed in the `Terms` attribute decorating `APInvoice.TermsID` field:

```
#region TermsID
public abstract class termsID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<termsID> { }

/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="PX.Objects.CS.Terms">credit terms</see> associated with the document (unavailable for prepayments and debit adjustments).\
/// Defaults to the <see cref="Vendor.TermsID">credit terms of the vendor</see>.
/// </summary>
[PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<Vendor.termsID,
    Where<Vendor.bAccountID, Equal<Current<APInvoice.vendorID>>,
        And<Current<APInvoice.docType>, NotEqual<APDocType.debitAdj>>>>),
    PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Terms", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[APTermsSelector]
[Terms(typeof(APInvoice.docDate), typeof(APInvoice.dueDate), typeof(APInvoice.discDate), 
       typeof(APInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt), typeof(APInvoice.curyOrigDiscAmt))]
public virtual string TermsID
{
    get;
    set;
}
#endregion
```

It is the last parameter of the `TermsAttribute` class constructor: `CuryDiscBal`

```
public TermsAttribute(Type DocDate, Type DueDate, Type DiscDate, Type CuryDocBal, Type CuryDiscBal)
{
    _DocDate = DocDate;
    _DueDate = DueDate;
    _DiscDate = DiscDate;
    _CuryDiscBal = CuryDiscBal;
    _CuryDocBal = CuryDocBal;
}
```

The final value is computed in the `CalcDisc` method of `Terms` attribute. It is assigned with `SetValue` method which does not raise events:

```
protected virtual void CalcDisc(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_CuryDocBal != null && _CuryDiscBal != null &&
            sender.GetValue(e.Row, _FieldName) != null &&
        sender.GetValue(e.Row, _CuryDocBal.Name) != null && !sender.Graph.IsCopyPasteContext)
    {
        string TermsID = (string)sender.GetValue(e.Row, _FieldName);
        decimal CuryDocBal = (decimal)sender.GetValue(e.Row, _CuryDocBal.Name);
        decimal CuryDiscBal = 0m;

        Terms terms = SelectTerms(sender.Graph, TermsID);
        if (terms != null && terms.InstallmentType == TermsInstallmentType.Single && CuryDocBal > 0m)
        {
            CuryDiscBal = PXDBCurrencyAttribute.Round(sender, e.Row, CuryDocBal * (decimal)terms.DiscPercent / 100, CMPrecision.TRANCURY);
        }

        sender.SetValue(e.Row, _CuryDiscBal.Name, CuryDiscBal);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(sender, e.Row, _CuryDiscBal.Name, (terms.InstallmentType == TermsInstallmentType.Single));
    }
}
```

To override it you could substitute the Terms attribute with a custom attribute based on the original `TermsAttribute` class. Then you  override field `APInvoice.TermsID` and decorate it with the custom attribute to replace the original Terms. Changing the `SetValue` assignment to use `SetValueExt` should raise the field updating/updated events.

Comment: So, really all I am doing is making CalcDisc raise the updating/update  events? If I am changing that method anyway, is there any reason why I just wouldn't change the CalcDisc method to make my additional calculations instead?

Comment: You can do it there but you'll have to pass additional fields/tables to the attribute if they are needed for the additional calculations.

Comment: (please see detail in question edit) would it be possible to raise the events without having to change the base code for CalcDisc () ?

Comment: Also, should I be doing this at the CacheAttached event for TermsId so it doesn't affect anything else using this DAC? (I'm looking for an example of this somewhere, any chance you have a link?)

Comment: > would it be possible to raise the events without having to change the base code for CalcDisc
- You can call RaiseFieldUpdated outside the attribute but I don't see how that would help/

Comment: Yes CacheAttached should be fine. You need to replace all attributes and change only the Terms.

Comment: OK, closed this question, because I am sure your answer is correct -- but my implementation of it must be wrong. If you get a chance can you check out this new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66876775/628887

Comment: There's not enough information to tell. Where is the CacheAttached located? I think it should replace all attribute not just Terms.

Comment: Oh and the custom attribute is almost empty. I would look there first, compare yours with the original, it's missing most logic.

Comment: In the original it is calling CalcDisc from FieldUpdated method, this method is missing in your custom attribute.