# Cannot get Events.CacheAttached to recognize custom Attribute in Acuamtica

Tags: c#, acumatica

This is a follow-up to the question I posted here [Override action on curyOrigDiscAmt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66827717/628887)

Following the advice there, I am trying to:

1. Create a custom attribute based on the original TermsAttribute
   class.
2. Override field APInvoice.TermsID
3. Decorate the field APInvoice.TermsID with the custom attribute and
   use this to replace the original Terms.
4. Finally change the logic of the CalcDisc() method

Here is what I have done:

**1. Custom Attribute:**

```
public class CTERMSIDAttribute : PX.Objects.CS.TermsAttribute
{
    public CTERMSIDAttribute(Type DocDate, Type DueDate, Type DiscDate, Type CuryDocBal, Type CuryDiscBal) : base(DocDate, DueDate, DiscDate, CuryDocBal, CuryDiscBal)
    {
        var cBalance = _CuryDocBal;
        var cDiscount = _CuryDiscBal;
        int i = 0;
    }

    protected override void CalcDisc(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.CalcDisc(sender, e);
        int i2 = 0;
        
    }
}
```

*NOTE: there is nothing being done in this for right now. I just put a break point on the int i = 0 to make sure my code is getting executed at run time.*

I also create a class that is decorated with the newly minted attribute:

```
public class CTermID : Vendor.termsID
{
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXDefault(typeof(Search<Vendor.termsID,
        Where<Vendor.bAccountID, Equal<Current<APInvoice.vendorID>>,
            And<Current<APInvoice.docType>, NotEqual<APDocType.debitAdj>>>>),
        PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Terms", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
    [APTermsSelector]
    [CTERMSIDAttribute(typeof(APInvoice.docDate), typeof(APInvoice.dueDate), typeof(APInvoice.discDate),
           typeof(APInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt), typeof(APInvoice.curyOrigDiscAmt))]
    public string termsID   { get;  set; }
}
```

I am not sure this is needed, nor used, but I saw it in a snippet, so I implemented it.

**2 & 3. Override and decorate**

```
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)] // add to other properties 
    [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(Vendor.termsID))]  // remove existing property
    [CTERMSIDAttribute(typeof(APInvoice.docDate), typeof(APInvoice.dueDate), typeof(APInvoice.discDate),
               typeof(APInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt), typeof(APInvoice.curyOrigDiscAmt))]
    public CTermID termsID { get; set; }   // redefine termsID to use custom attribute
    protected virtual void _(Events.CacheAttached<APInvoice.termsID> e)
    {
        int i3 = 0;
    }
```

**4. Override Method for CalcDisc()**

This is in the new attribute (previously shown in step 1):

```
    protected override void CalcDisc(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.CalcDisc(sender, e);
        int i2 = 0;            
    }
```

Again, it doesn't do anything right now, I just put a breakpoint at the int i2 = 0 to check if it is hitting at runtime. And it isn't.

What happens is that the first breakpoint (i=0) hits.. in fact it hits several times... but none of the others do, which tells me that the override isn't working correctly.

What am I missing?

[EDIT]
Per Patrick Chen's suggestion, I changed it to this:

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]
[CTERMSIDAttribute(typeof(APInvoice.docDate), typeof(APInvoice.dueDate), typeof(APInvoice.discDate), typeof(APInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt), typeof(APInvoice.curyOrigDiscAmt))]
public CTermID termsID { get; set; }   // redefine termsID to use custom attribute
protected virtual void _(Events.CacheAttached<APInvoice.termsID> e)
      {
        int i = 0;
      }
```

And still my version of DoCalc() is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dropping this statement

```
 [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(Vendor.termsID))]
```

and go with

```
 [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]
```

along with whatever stock attributes from Vendor you want to use.

Comment: I may misunderstood what you were suggesting, but I made the change you suggested (I think) and the result was the same (see edit in original question) Thanks!

Comment: drop the public CTermID termsID { get; set; }   statement as well.

Comment: Right. Duh! But, I am still not getting my attributes overrides to run. (One thing that is frustrating is I can't set breakpoints in there to see what is happening.)

Comment: The call to CalcDisc is in the base class FieldUpdated event. Because the call is in the base class it will continue to call the base class method instead of the override.

Comment: You effectively override the method in the custom attribute but no one is calling it. That's why you need the FieldUpdated method in your custom attribute instead of in the base class because that's the only call to CalcDisc.

Answer (score 0):

There's no mechanism to call `CalcDisc` method in your custom attribute.

In `TermsAttribute` a `FieldUpdated` event handler is used to call the `CalcDisc` method:
[image]

This `FieldUpdated` method is not present in the custom attribute so the method isn't called by any mechanism. The custom attribute has to follow more closely the original implementation which has about a dozen methods.

Comment: Where do I find the original implementation?

Comment: On Source Code page SM204570, search for 'class TermsAttribute'. There's a single result. A copy.paste of the original attribute with a different name will likely yield the same result as the original attribute.

Comment: But, this makes the customization I am making vulnerable to any future updates to the class. I would much rather simply call the base behavior, and then insert my code after that -- such as how I handle events in a windows form application, for example. That is a challenge in this case, though, since the attribute has private methods, that cannot be called from my attribute extension class. Anyway... thanks, I understand how to do this now.

Comment: Exact, it is not possible to override private/internal methods.